# Using DATE() with a SELECT

Tags: mysql

When querying my MySQL database, I use the line

```
SELECT `playlistDate` from `tracks` GROUP BY `playlistDate`
```

The JSON-ified result statement is this

```
[{"playlistDate":"2020-09-14T05:00:00.000Z"},{"playlistDate":"2020-09-21T05:00:00.000Z"},
{"playlistDate":"2020-09-28T05:00:00.000Z"},{"playlistDate":"2020-10-05T05:00:00.000Z"},
{"playlistDate":"2020-10-12T05:00:00.000Z"},{"playlistDate":"2020-10-19T05:00:00.000Z"},
{"playlistDate":"2020-10-26T05:00:00.000Z"},{"playlistDate":"2020-11-02T06:00:00.000Z"}
```

I want it to look like this, without the timestamps

```
[{"playlistDate":"2020-09-14"},{"playlistDate":"2020-09-21"},
{"playlistDate":"2020-09-28"},{"playlistDate":"2020-10-05"},
{"playlistDate":"2020-10-12"},{"playlistDate":"2020-10-19"},
{"playlistDate":"2020-10-26"},{"playlistDate":"2020-11-02"}
```

I've tried changing my query to either of these with no luck

```
SELECT DATE(`playlistDate` from `tracks` GROUP BY `playlistDate`)

SELECT DATE(`playlistDate`) from `tracks` GROUP BY `playlistDate`
```

How can I use the `DATE()` function to get the results I am expecting?

Comment: I would just store a timestamp, then you can just `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(playlistDate)*1000 d FROM tracks GROUP BY d` so you you can pass into the JavaScript `const dt = new Date(resultHere)`, this way the Client will see their play time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ugly way to do it is using  `substr(playlistDate, 1, 10)`.

You also can use `DATE_FORMAT(playlistDate,'%y-%m-%d')`

Comment: In terms of my query, would that make it SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`playlistDate`,'%Y/%m/%d') from `tracks` GROUP BY `playlistDate`

Comment: Yes... but remove the useless group by here. If you want unicity, use `distinct( date_format(...) )`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming playlistDate is a string, you can use `STR_TO_DATE`.

```
SELECT distinct(STR_TO_DATE(playlistDate,'%Y/%m/%d')) from tracks
```

If its a date:

```
SELECT distinct(DATE_FORMAT(playlistDate,'%Y/%m/%d')) from tracks
```